# CSS variables – :root not working in media query

Tags: css, css-variables

I can't figure out why this media query is not working. The media query is always referring to the first instance of the `:root` variables instead of the `:root` variables inside the media query.

```
// Outside media query
:root {
  --default: 10px;
}

DIV {
  width: var(--default);
}

//Inside media query
@media screen and (max-width: 55rem) {
  :root {
    --default: 500px;
  }
  
  DIV {
    width: var(--default);
  }
}
```

This always results in the h1 tag being 10px wide instead of 500px wide, even if the media query. (Testing in Chrome and iOS Safari.)

Any tips?

I'm following this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-responsiveness-super-simple-with-css-variables-8c90ebf80d7f/

---

**DEMO**

```js
const log = () => console.log(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--default'));

log();
window.addEventListener('resize', log);
```

```css
:root {
  --default: 10px;
}

h1 {
  width: var(--default);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 55rem) {
   :root {
    --default: 500px;
  }
  h1 {
    width: var(--default);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>HEADING</h1>
```

Comment: Maybe you don't enter in the condition max-width:55rem, try to set max-width 480px and see if it works (just for test). If you have 16px font-size for body your 55rem = 880px;

Comment: Your code is working for me

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the media query actually works/fires. I tried it with other properties. :/

Comment: Daniel_Knights, that's weird, thanks for testing though.

Comment: I added a snippet to your post. What does the console log say for you?

Comment: I found out, that it actually loads the `:root` variables found inside the media query but only for a split second, then it reverts back to the non `:root` variables.

Comment: if you expect to *see* something different, you won't. Your text will simply overflow the 10px width but you will get the same result as with 500px

Comment: EDIT: Console says 500px

Comment: Temani Afif, there's not text, H1 was just an example container, I edited it to DIV for clarity.

Comment: That's really odd, it says `500px` and then changes to `10px` when made larger for me. I'm using Chrome

Comment: The split second loading is kind of weird.

Comment: I found the culprit: it was a misconfiguration on my side in the CSS vars ponyfill plugin. Thanks everyone for your help! It's this one https://jhildenbiddle.github.io/css-vars-ponyfill/#/